# d3.js difference chart area transitions

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having trouble getting the area portions of a difference chart to properly execute transitions.

As I am still learning, the chart is based on Mike Bostock's Difference Chart example and the transitions were guided by d3noob's [transitions post](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/update-d3js-data-dynamically-button.html).

Relevant bits:

```
  svgchin.select("#clip-above-chin path")
    .duration(750)
    .attr("d", area.y0(0));

  svgchin.select("#clip-below-chin path")
    .duration(750)
    .attr("d", area.y0(height));

  svgchin.select(".area.above")
    .duration(750)
    .attr("d", area.y0(function(d) { return y(d["Post"]); }));

  svgchin.select(".area.below")
    .duration(750)
    .attr("d", area);
```

Full jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/uxb3yq9g/6/

As you can see, the lines and axes update as intended. The areas, however, are not yet on board.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't actually updated the data bound to the elements. Just do

```
var svgchin = d3.select("#chinook").datum(data).transition();
```

and everything works fine. Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uxb3yq9g/7/).